# xaml Binding to nested property of singleton

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, singleton

I have a `Singleton` Class

```
public sealed class GlobalTranslator
    {
        public Translator Translator = new Translator();

        static readonly GlobalTranslator INSTANCE = new GlobalTranslator();

        private GlobalTranslator()
        {

        }

        public static GlobalTranslator Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return INSTANCE;
            }
        }
    }
```

That will allow me to define a Culture for my `Translator` Class

```
public class Translator : MarkupExtension
{
    readonly CultureInfo Ci;
    const string ResourceId = "LDVELH_WPF.Resources.Strings";

    public Translator()
    {
        Ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    }
    public Translator(String language)
    {
        switch (language.ToLower())
        {
            case "french":
                Ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
                break;
            case "english":
                Ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
                break;
            default:
                Ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
                break;
        }
    }
    public Translator(SupportedLanguage language)
    {
        switch (language)
        {
            case SupportedLanguage.French:
                Ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
                break;
            case SupportedLanguage.English:
                Ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
                break;
            default:
                Ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
                break;
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    override public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return "";

        ResourceManager Resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId
                            , typeof(Translator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        return Resmgr.GetString(Text, Ci);
    }
    public string ProvideValue(string stringToTranslate)
    {
            Text = stringToTranslate;
            if (Text == null)
                return "";

            ResourceManager Resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId
                                , typeof(Translator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            return Resmgr.GetString(Text, Ci);
    }
}
```

Before I when only used my Translator Class, I could bind like that :

```
Content="{Core:Translator Text=MyText}"
```

Setting my Text property would call my `ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` method, and so I would be binding on my resource.string of MyText.

Now that I have multiple language, I'm trying to do the same, using my `GlobalTranslator`.
I could add a reference to my `GlobalTranslator.Instance` by doing

```
<Window.Resources>
        <x:StaticExtension Member="Core:GlobalTranslator.Instance" x:Key="MyGlobalTranslator"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

but I can't seem to find a way to do something like

```
Content="{MyGlobalTranslator.Translator Text=MyText}"
```

I can still do it in the code behind by

```
MyButton.Content = GlobalTranslator.Instance.Translator.ProvideValue("MyText");
```

But would like to know if there's a way to do it in xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix my problem I've had to refactor quite a bit of code.

When initialising the component the View Create a new `Translator` each time, I wanted this `Translator` to take into account the `CultureInfo` Selected, so I created a new `Singleton` `GlobalCulture`, and instead of getting my `CultureInfo Ci` from my `Translator`, I take it straight from my `GlobalCulture`.
This way it doesn't matter if I work with my `GlobalTranslator` or a new `Translator` initialised by my View `InitializeComponent`, I will always get the right `CultureInfo`.

My `Translator` now looks like that :

```
public class Translator : MarkupExtension
{
const string ResourceId = "LDVELH_WPF.Resources.Strings";

public Translator()
{
}

public string Text
{
    get;
    set;
}

override public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (Text == null)
        return "";

    ResourceManager Resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId
                        , typeof(Translator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

    return Resmgr.GetString(Text, GlobalCulture.Instance.Ci);
}
public string ProvideValue(string stringToTranslate)
{
        Text = stringToTranslate;
        if (Text == null)
            return "";

        ResourceManager Resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId
                            , typeof(Translator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        return Resmgr.GetString(Text, GlobalCulture.Instance.Ci);
}
}
```

And when I'm changing my language setting instead of doing :  `GlobalTranslator.Instance.Translator = new Translator(language);`

I do :
`GlobalCulture.Instance.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo(language);`

And so I can set my Text in XAML via `Content="{Core:Translator Text=MyText}"`